# Selenium Fill in all input fields at once Java

Tags: java, selenium

I wanted to fill in all the Text fields at the same time using selenium. How would i got about doing this in java? With this code when i execute the code, each Text field gets filled in one by one which is pretty slow

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

WebElement fullname = driver.findElement(By.id("order_billing_name"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='Test Name';", fullname);
WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("order_email"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='test123@gmail.com';", email);
WebElement tel = driver.findElement(By.id("order_tel"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='12345678901';", tel);
WebElement address = driver.findElement(By.id("bo"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='123 Main Street';", address);
WebElement city = driver.findElement(By.id("order_billing_city"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='London';", city);
WebElement postcode = driver.findElement(By.id("order_billing_zip"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='LE1 123';", postcode);
WebElement number = driver.findElement(By.id("cnb"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='1234567890123456';", number);
WebElement cvv = driver.findElement(By.id("vval"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='123';", cvv);
```

Comment: can you explain your question more, can you add the scenario ?

Comment: The current script essentially sends keys one by one to each of the text fields which is pretty slow

Comment: Is Selenium's .sendKeys() not working or is it somehow even slower?  What is your browser?  If it's IE, that probably explains the "sends keys one by one"  IE is horribly slow.  You can actually see the keystrokes as if they were being typed.  If that's your scenario, you might be trying to run the 64-bit version of IE - don't do that, run the 32-bit version.  Still slower than Chrome or FF, but better than the 64-bit version.

Comment: I am using Chrome, ChromeDriver 32bit version and i have found using executing script is faster than sending keys because it is visually typing in some text whereas executing the script fills the text field instantly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);  

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("order_billing_name"))).sendKeys("Test Name");  

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("order_email"))).sendKeys("test123@gmail.com");  

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("order_tel"))).sendKeys("12345678901");  

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("bo"))).sendKeys("123 Main Street");  

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("order_billing_city"))).sendKeys("London");  

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("order_billing_zip"))).sendKeys("LE1 123");  

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("cnb"))).sendKeys("1234567890123456");  

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("vval"))).sendKeys("123");
```

Comment: This code is still filling out the text fields one by one

Comment: this is the only work around we have in selenium. How can you send all the values at one shot ?